# Convert from Task<AuthenticationResult> to AuthenticationResult

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I have a result as:

```
var authResult = DoSomething
```

It returns Task

> How to convert: Task to AuthenticationResult

This AuthenticationResult I have to pass in a class method as parameter.

```
Class1 A = new Class1()

A.Method1(AuthenticationResult)
```

Comment: `await` the task to get its result (this will make your method `async`) or use `GetAwaiter().Value` (if you can't)

Comment: Use async/await pattern

Comment: It returns `Task` because that's an asynchronous operation that *hasn't* finished yet. Use `await` to await for it to finish, get the result and continue on the original thread without blocking while waiting. `async/await` is covered extensively in the MSDN docs, blogs, courses etc. *DON'T* try to block the task with `.Wait()` or `.Result`. This will freeze your thread instead of waiting asynchronously. That's what happens when eg you see a desktop application freeze while waiting to connect

Answer (score 0):

You can always get `T` from `Task<T>` writing :

```
var task = DoSomething(); // type Task<T>
var result = task.Result; // type T
```

If `DoSomething()` allows you to, you can use the async/await pattern :

```
var result = await DoSomethong(); // type T
```

Comment: Blocking on a task is a bad idea

Comment: You should *never* access `.Result` unless you know it has completed; the `await DoSomething()` is fine, but you should really have a `if(task.IsCompleted) {...}` barrier around the first

Comment: `DoSomething` has nothing at all to do with whether you can use `await` in the calling method. *All* methods that return a taks can be used with `await`, as long as the *calling method* has the `async` keyword. You don't need to know anything about `DoSomething()` apart from the fact that it returns a `Task<T>`

Answer (score 0):

If you *cannot* use the `async/await` keywords, consider using TPL (Task Parallel Library) directly, through the continuations mechanism.

```
Class1 A = new Class1();

Task<AuthenticationResult> authenticationTask = DoSomething();

// Register an Action<Task<T>> to run when the task has transitioned RanToCompletion 
// or Faulted
authenticationTask.ContinueWith(p =>
{
    if(p.IsFaulted) // Handle any exceptions!
    {
        Exception ex = p.Exception
    }
    else
    {
        // Success! :D Process the result as usual.
        // Task<T>.Result is an instance of T - in our case, AuthenticationResult. 
        // It would be default(T) if a task has faulted or has not completed. 
        // At this point, we are confident that the task has completed without a fault.
        A.Method1(p.Result);
    }
});
```

The downside here is that you are not able to return a final value from this method without a bit more plumbing. `async/await` does all of this for you but it is achievable. There are also no guarentees that you will be running on the original thread (commonly required in UI scenarios) but this is also achievable. You can find the answers to these issues in another question.